# docker-compose yaml - option to pass the 'ulimit' parameters 'rtprio' and 'memlock'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, real-time, ulimit

I can't find the option in the docker-compose.yaml to pass the parameters the following 'docker' parameters:

`--ulimit rtprio=95 --ulimit memlock=-1`

In other words, I wish to wrap the following command with docker-compose:

`docker run --rm -it --network host --ulimit rtprio=95 --ulimit memlock=-1 --name my_proj image/my_image bash`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a per-service dictionary called [`ulimits:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ulimits).

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_proj:
    image: image/my_image
    ulimits:
      rtprio: 95
      memlock: -1
    ...
```

Note that Docker Compose works better with non-interactive services that stay running; I would use it to launch your service proper and not necessarily to get an interactive shell in a temporary container.

Comment: I used 'bash' just for the example.
Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score -1):

ulimits is depricated

> Note: This replaces the older resource constraint options for non
>   swarm mode in Compose files prior to version 3 (cpu_shares, cpu_quota,
>   cpuset, mem_limit, memswap_limit, mem_swappiness), as described in
>   Upgrading version 2.x to 3.x.

(Source: [docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources))

```
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 8g
    reservations:
      memory: 4g
```

Comment: Not true. ulimits is still used in version 3. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ulimits

Comment: above is correct, also there's no "limit" option for core dump size

Comment: links are outdated