# docker-compose.yml way of setting coredump lengths to unlimited?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, resources, limit

I've googled about this for hours, but didn't find much.

I found "ulimits" in the docker-compose, but apparently it's deprecated, and I don't see anything (so far) in its replacement ("resources") about core dump sizes.

Inside the container, I can't change my ulimit -c - I get:

```
root@celery_worker:/app# ulimit -c unlimited
bash: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

But outside docker, in an unprivileged (bash on MacOS) shell, I get:

```
$ ulimit -c
cmd output started 2022 Mon Feb 14 04:36:45 PM PST
0
above cmd output done    2022 Mon Feb 14 04:36:45 PM PST
dastromberg@RE-dastromberg-ML:~ x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0 13312

$ ulimit -c unlimited
cmd output started 2022 Mon Feb 14 04:36:49 PM PST
above cmd output done    2022 Mon Feb 14 04:36:49 PM PST
dastromberg@RE-dastromberg-ML:~ x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0 13312
```

I need this inside a container, so I'm guessing I need to set it outside, in a way that Docker Desktop is going to see.

Is there a docker-compose.yml way of doing this?  Or perhaps a Docker Desktop way?

Thanks!

Comment: Compose has a [`ulimits:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ulimits) block.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'd heard that ulimits was deprecated, but reading further, perhaps it isn't really: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387308/docker-compose-yaml-option-to-pass-the-ulimit-parameters-rtprio-and-memlo

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have fixed it, in my docker-compose.yml:

```
# https://github.com/docker/go-units/blob/f2145db703495b2e525c59662db69a7344b00bb8/ulimit.go#L46-L62
# https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-yml-ulimits/59330
ulimits:
  core:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
```

I was unable to use "unlimited", but the -1's seem to work for my purposes.